# concurrency semantics reading a file being written (ext)

Tags: concurrency, file-systems

In [Ext 3/4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3) filesystem, if I have a log file open and being appended to, if another process tries to read it (e.g. with `cat`), what happens?

1. Can the reading process read part of / an incomplete write?
2. Is reading-during-writing safe and won't disrupt the writing process?  Or is there a chance the logs can be corrupted by doing this?

Where should one read more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Can the reading process read part of / an incomplete write?**
The reading process will only be able to read the data that has been written, but to answer the question, yes it could read part of the data if the write has not yet completed.

**2. Is reading-during-writing safe and won't disrupt the writing process? Or is there a chance the logs can be corrupted by doing this?**

Reading during writing, although not entirely safe, should not disrupt the writing process. Neither will it necessarily corrupt the logs, but any data that is does manage to read will likely be incomplete.

Ultimately I wouldn't recommend it.